# Mean vs. Median nearest-neighbor spacing

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have a density of points $n = \frac{points}{volume}$ in a $d$-dimensional space.  An analysis of the points indicates that, to the best of your knowledge, they are distributed randomly via a Poisson process.

What is the smaller quantity: the mean distance from a point to its nearest-neighbor, or the median distance of a point to its nearest-neighbor?  Does this change as a function of the density $n$ or the dimension $d$?  In three-dimensions, it seems like the median nearest-neighbor spacing tends to be smaller than the mean nearest-neighbor spacing.

We can calculate the average (or mean) nearest-neighbor spacing as $\approx \frac{1}{n^{(\frac{1}{d})}}$.  Let the space be very large in order that we come as close to this approximation as possible.  It isn't so clear to me how to calculate the median nearest-neighbor spacing.